# JpaRepository, can I mock a repository while asserting the created query string?

Tags: java, jpa, testing, mockito

So, I have an application that is accessible through REST and we use a `JpaRepository<T>` to store and retrieve data.

I have written some `mockMvc` tests where we test if the endpoint can be reached and the repository is called with the correct parameters.

Example:

```java
mockMvc.perform(put("path")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .characterEncoding("UTF8")
                .content(t)
        ).andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON));

Mockito.verify(tRepo.save(t));
```

I was wondering is there a way/ library which allows the query that the repository will create to be asserted? So i can also assert that the repository creates the correct sql-statement. Without using a h2 or containerized database?

Pseudo code example:

```java
assertEquals(
  capturedSqlStatement,
  "INSERT INTO t (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);"
);
```

Comment: Even if it is possible (and I don't think it is), by doing so you would be testing someone else's code (Spring Framework) and not yours.

Comment: In the example that i have given this would be obviously the case. However in the project that i have started working on are far more complex queries and inserts that makes us question whether ORM is interpreting the code correctly

Comment: ORM will interpret the code correctly, what could be wrong is the code that does not match your Database schema. But that is something you can only cover with a fully-fledged integration test.

Comment: The problem is that the SQL may not look the same depending on the underlaying database. IMHO (and that's really just my opinion) database tests without the real database do not make much sense

Comment: I will consider this thanks for the remarks.